# Vertically center element without it becoming inaccessible offscreen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center an element in the middle of the page. I can center it just fine, but if I resize the page vertically until the view height is smaller than the centered element, the element goes offscreen vertically without a scrollbar. You can see a demonstration of the issue here:

http://codepen.io/mse/pen/BWayXV

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.outer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

I should mention that I have tried a couple of other methods of vertical centering, including flexbox, and I'm still running into the same issue. Is there a way to solve this problem with this method of vertical centering, or is there at least a vertical centering method that does not have this issue?

Comment: Don't understand, what effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm looking for the top of the element to stop at the top of the page if the viewport is smaller than the element's height. It doesn't do that at the moment. It keeps moving upward offscreen without access via the scrollbar.

Comment: I get a scrollbar (chrome)

Comment: I only get a scrollbar downwards. The top of the div gets cut off without the ability to scroll up. It's hard to see in the codepen because there's no content in the inner div, but it does get cut off..

Comment: You could give your outer div a max height and make the inner scroll if content is too much: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvyoKd

Comment: Yep, that looks like the best solution so far. Thanks Pete!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}
.outer {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
        <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to just align it to the top of the page. There's no vertically centering at all. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxYOBJ

Answer (score 0):

You can try to limit the size of your inner element. If you define size by a fixed px amount it will start scrolling as soon as the screen becomes smaller than that px amount. If you are ok with changing the height of the inner element you could use `vh` or you can implement `@media` queries to decrease the size on smaller screens. Here#s an example:

```
.inner { height: 100vh; /* 100 view height percentage*/}
```

*Note: The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block and affected by the presence of scrollbars on the viewport.*

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  In particular, you should note which version of the standard defines the `vh` unit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.outer {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.inner {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"> I'm a block-level element centered vertically within my parent.</div>
</div>
```

More info: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

CSS VH center generator: http://howtocenterincss.com/